# How to get the username of the user accessing ASP.NET intranet page within local network?

Tags: asp.net, authentication, intranet, userid

We have an ASP.NET intranet site, available to users who are either physically at and logged into a local machine or else to users who connect remotely via VPN.  Is there a way to automatically get the username of whoever is accessing the page based on the name used to either log into the local machine or that used for the VPN?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is possible if you're using Windows Authentication in your pages.

You can use either `Page.User.Identity.Name` or the more complete `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name`.

Read more about it here:

[Enabling Windows Authentication within an Intranet ASP.NET Web Application](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/07/12/Recipe_3A00_-Enabling-Windows-Authentication-within-an-Intranet-ASP.NET-Web-application.aspx)

If you are, however, using Forms Authentication, you'll have to keep track of the current user yourself, the most common method of which will be by storing their login name in a Session variable.

Comment: Just a note but if you use forms authentication `User.Identity.Name` will also contains the forms auth username as well.

Answer (score 3):

If the authentication is setup to do Integrated Windows authentication then you should be able to get it by accessing

```
User.Identity.Name
```

Answer (score 3):

Get the `User` information as follows:

```
User.Identity.Name \\ Get the User name
User.Identity.AuthenticationType \\ What is the Authentication type
User.Identity.IsAuthenticated \\ Is he authenticated?
User.IsInRole("Administrators") \\ Is he administrator?
```

Answer (score 1):

If the authentication is windows, this should help:

```
IIdentity WinId= HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;
WindowsIdentity wi = (WindowsIdentity)WinId;
```

Comment: are you using Forms or Windows authentication?

Comment: Turns out the problem was that our admin had set anonymous access to true

Comment: aah i see. check out the section on anonymous access http://www.eggheadcafe.com/articles/20050703.asp

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
Page.User.Identity.Name
```