# How to read username which is logged in by VPN in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the requirement when any remote user log in by using VPN , my ASP.Net application must be able to read the username.

I just want to read the username which is loging in by VPN and my ASP.Net application works inside VPN.

Note: That username is not same as Active directory and Windows User, also I don't want to read Windows User ID.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried. Where you are stuck or getting error?

Comment: did you checked that one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/761016/get-the-username-of-the-user-accessing-asp-net-intranet-page-within-local-networ

Comment: Dear Hazem, I have tried the thing which is shown in the link you have provided, but this is returning the windows login ID and i need the VPN user id by which the user will login to the vpn site first like vpn.xxx.xxx and then provide user name and password and then comes to my application. At the login of my application i want to use VPN user id

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the thing which is shown in the link you have provided, but this is returning the windows login ID and i need the VPN user id by which the user will login to the vpn site first like vpn.xxx.xxx and then provide user name and password and then comes to my application. At the login of my application i want to use VPN user id